# Magento 2 Model getData for field at specific store_id

Tags: model, magento2.2.2, store-view, data

In my Model I have a method `getSummary()` E.G:

```
public function getSummary() {
        return $this->getData(BlogInterface::SUMMARY);
    }
```

I have 3 stores: `en_1,fr_2,de_3`

I've only set `summary` in the default store view therefore the summary will have `store_id = 0`;

What I have tried:

```
public function getSummary() {
            $this->setStoreId('0'); //try setting store id to fetch summary for store view 0
            return $this->getData(BlogInterface::SUMMARY);
        }
```

My DB field: notice `store_id` field has `0` with `<p>Default Summary</<p>`
[image]

I've also tried `return $this->getData(BlogInterface::Summary, '0');`

Any ideas how one can fetch specific field data for specific store id?

Best!

Comment: Is this your custom table right?

Comment: @RaviSoni Yes it is!

Comment: And you want to get store_id 0 summary value?

Comment: @RaviSoni  Yes I do!

Comment: So you can add filter on your collection. like :  $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 0);

Comment: @RaviSoni  Wouldn't that load all field for a `store_id` but some filed has data other don't so basically if I land on `store_id 2` and a field has no data I need to load only for that field the data in `store_id 0` which is the default. Yes that would!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95577/discussion-between-ravi-soni-and-juliano-vargas).

Comment: Did you created eav module or you have specific field in "store_id" in your table?

Comment: Yes eav module with tables etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 0 or current store_id. You can check this way:

```
$storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$collection = $this->customCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addFieldToFilter(
                        'store_id',
                        [
                            ['eq' => 0],
                            ['finset' => $storeId]
                        ])
                      ;
```